# Turing machine symbols

Tags: symbols

I'm trying to write a paper in LaTeX involving Turing Machines, and I was wondering if there is a way to write the symbol that denotes the blank in LaTeX. They have written it in the textbook I'm using, so there must be a way to do it, but I can't find anything that gives the command for that symbol.

Comment: Maybe it's `\textvisiblespace` you're looking for?

Comment: Kind of. It looks like that, but the sides are taller.

Comment: Maybe `\sqcup` (in math mode) then?

Comment: Taller sides could just be a different font - it might not be a different character.

Comment: Could you please add an image or point to a resource on the net showing what you're after?